# Create file in Azure file storage ( File share ) using REST API ( No native Azure storage account conn string usage )

Tags: c#

I am following below link to write REST API to create file in azure file share. Type of storage account is file storage. I am getting http return code 200 and not 201 and file is not created. Please help.

http://staplessoftware.com/authorizing-azure-file-service-create-file-example

Comment: 200 is a status OK which is the correct response.  Why do you think you are suppose to get a 201?

Comment: please take a look at ms link for create file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file. As per this status successful creation of file should return 201. Moreover I dont see file created in file share

Comment: You are right the response should be a 201 (not 200). Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if your request looks like the sample request on your latest link. Check for following 1) Using HTTP or HTTPS 2) Using HTTP(s) 1.0 or HTTP(s) 1.1 3) Check body of request to see if you have Base 64 String (no binary) 4) Check Content Length 5) Check sniffer and see if TLS is being used and version.  Will occur before the HTTP Request.

Comment: I am using https but even with http error is same.Code from this link - http://staplessoftware.com/authorizing-azure-file-service-create-file-example always gives status back 200 even if I provide wrong storage account or key. I dont know why. Now I am writing my own code and that gives 403 error. Does anyone has working code on how to create file on azure storage with shared key, specially on how to construct that signed authorize string.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files

Comment: Above link is by using SDK. Thats fairly easy and I am able to do file operations with SDK. Somehow my company also want to explore REST option in case our customers dont have SDK installed. I am following up with Microsoft now since I am out of ideas.

Comment: Why don't you simply debug the server code.  As far as I see the Github code only returns 200 and not 201.  See : https://github.com/mstaples84/azurefileserviceauth/blob/master/SimpleAzureFileServiceDemo/AzureFileService.cs